# Pre-compilation of Speak Views Required on every application initialize (app start)

Tags: performance-optimization, speak

[image]

I know Speak views (180+) are pre-complied on every app initialize ( application start) which is to optimize the performance of speak component.
Also developers can disable them if they need quick application start when they are working in sandbox environment as mentioned here:
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/maximize-sitecore-developer-productivity
https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/development/improving_performance_by_disabling_precompilation_of_mvc_views

My Queries are:

1. When there are no changes to Sitecore Speak component views why do
   we need pre-compilation between two application starts which happens
   sequentially.Any technique to control pre-compilation where are no changes ?
2. Does this Pre-compilation at application initialize meant only for
   SPEAK views provided by sitecore or even to custom SPEAK Views
   created by dev team.  Just by providing path something here
   **/Areas/MyAreas/Views/CustomSpeak.cshtml**

[image: One of Speak View's path]
( I have not tested this & also worried on application start duration )

Answer (score 1):

I have taken this to Sitecore support team & got the response. :)

**Question:** When there are no changes to Sitecore Speak component views why do we need pre-compilation between two application starts which happens sequentially.Any technique to control pre-compilation when there are no changes ?

**Support Team Answer:** There is no out of the box way to keep track of the changes and making decisions on that basis. This can make the performance even more worse if we check every file to decide if we need a compilation again or not. So If you want to increase performance you can use the ways provided in following articles.
https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/development/improving_performance_by_disabling_precompilation_of_mvc_views
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/maximize-sitecore-developer-productivity

**Question:** Does this Pre-compilation at application initialize meant only for SPEAK views provided by sitecore or even to custom SPEAK Views created by dev team. Just by providing path something here /Areas/MyAreas/Views/CustomSpeak.cshtml

**Support Team Answer:** You can use root path for your custom views for example in your case, /Areas/MyAreas/Views/ would be enough.

***Take way points:***
We can optimize areas MVC views just by providing root path in the below processor of initialize pipeline (tested it locally, working fine) :)

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Initialize.PrecompileSpeakViews, Sitecore.Speak.Client" patch:source="Sitecore.Speak.config"><Paths>/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library</Paths><Paths>/Areas/MyAreas/Views/</Paths></processor>
```

Comment: That's really good to know! Thank you for posting the answer!

Comment: Are these changes applicable to SC9.0.2 because unable to find configuration attributes?